# How to retrieve the `event` object if the DOMContentLoaded event has been triggered before setting a listener

Tags: javascript, events

Is there a way to retrieve the `event` object of the `DOMContentLoaded` event even if it has been triggered before setting an eventListener?

I have found some timing data for `DOMContentLoaded` and was hoping the event data might be stored as well.

```
window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventStart
window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd
```

I would like to pass the `event` object to my callback whether it was called directly or as a result of the eventlistener.

```
var callback = function(event){
    console.log(event)
}
if (document.readyState !== "loading") {
    var event = window.DOMContentLoadedEvent; // doesnt exist
    callback.call(this, event);
} else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', callback, false)
}
```

I suppose I could create a new object and return that but i would like my code a small as possible.

```
var event = {
    srcElement: document,
    target:document,
    timeStamp:window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd,
    type:"DOMContentLoaded",
}
callback.call(this, event);
```

What I have done instead is to add another event listener which will definitely be registered before the `DOMContentLoaded` event if fired, the handler stores the `event` object;

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event){
    window.DOMContentLoadedEvent = event; 
});
```

#### Edit

My code is a very simple domready function

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event){
    window.DOMContentLoadedEvent = event; 
});
domready = function(callback) {

    if (document.readyState === "loading") {
      return document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', callback, false);
    }
    return callback.call(this, window.DOMContentLoadedEvent);
}
```

The following code may reside in an external script an be inserted after the `DOMContentLoaded` event has fired.

```
domready(function(event){
    console.log(event)
});
```

Am I able to retrieve the `event` data without setting up an additional event listener ?

Comment: `window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventStart` and 
`window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd` are timestamps. Not certain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: yep.., As domContentLoaded timestamps are stored, i was hoping some other data might be hidden away in the window object somewhere.

Comment: What data are you trying to retrieve? Could you use single `document.addEventListerner("DOMContentLoaded")` ? The event would be called at most once, yes?

Comment: Yes the event will be called only once but there may be multiple handlers. As the callbacks will differ i would like to the full event object available to the callback whether is is used or not..

Comment: `DOMContentLoaded` is the first event, fired in browser (am I right?), and it fires ONLY after all `<scripts>` were processed (!!! AND thay are not async or deffered!)

Comment: yep, the domready function may be used within an async script.

Answer (score -1):

check this:

```
<body>
...
<script>

    var DOMevent; // global variable

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
        DOMevent = event; // save it
    }, false);

    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        processEvent(DOMevent);  // works fine
    }, false);

    function processEvent(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
</script>
</body>
```

`console.log(e);` will show `DOMevent`.

more about `readyState`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState

more about `DOMContentLoaded` event

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

more about 'load' event

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load *typo in example! `document` -> `window`!

Comment: just realised i was using the wrong readystate, thanks for the links.